# Speech Recognition for Linux-Python

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition

I searched google and this site too. I could find Dragonfly is the best suited! But I couldn't find any perfect installation for this on Linux. And it seems it has no support as the last release date backs to 2009!

Nuance is the other company which toped my search. But it doesnot give linux support natively but can be done using HTTP request which is a costly affair and limited as it requires internet.

Can someone suggest me some kind of Speech recognition software for application building with python (Preferably cross platform / Linux)

Thanks IN Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) supports Python across various platforms. It seems well-suited to your needs.